# Explain asymptotic optimality property of AIC (Akaike information criterion)

Tags: aic, asymptotics, optimal

I am trying to use AIC in my research, I know how to apply it and how to interpret its value, but I do not understand the asymptotic optimality property in general and why AIC has this property. Can you guys explain in a simple manner what asymptotic optimality property means and How AIC criterion has this property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in the literature? Also, we have quite many threads on AIC, some of them extensive, and the answer to your question might very well be lurking in one (or more) of them. Check them out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aic?tab=Votes).

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your reply. I read many paper in literature and there was no clear definition for asymptotic optimality. I understand AIC but I do not understand what asymptotic optimality property mean and how it is a property for AIC